# if is specific custom post in cpt

Tags: php, conditional-tags, codex

I need to be able to target a specific post in a CPT.

According to the codex I can use the following code to reference a specific custom post type;

```
`if( is_singular ('cpt-name') {

//Something here

}
```

I need to target a post within a CPT. For example CPT = 'Books',  CPT-single = 'harry-potter'.

So in this example, I need to target 'harry-potter' not all  books as the `is_singular` allows.

The codex doesn't seem to specify a way to achieve what I want.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible using some function (I can be completely wrong though).
What you can do is check page slug using if() statement.
Something like:

```
global $post;
$post_slug=$post->post_name;
if($post_slug=='harry-potter'){
    //something here
}
```